# Hi, I have a question about Bluetooth profile

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-profile

I'm making a speech recognize App.
But there is problem.

App have to listen user's voice, So Bluetooth profile change to sco.
But I want to change Bluetooth profile to A2dp when I listen the music.

The Service can close by AudioManager.isMusicActive() but it can't change back A2dp.

Is there answer for it? I know that 2 profile can't be incompatible.

So, When i use for speech recognize , Bluetooth profile -> Sco
When i listen to music, Bluetooth profile -> A2dp

How can i handle it?